# ORACLE APEX 5.0 Hourly/Minute Interactive Report Subscription

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

Default Subscription for Interactive Reports in Oracle Apex is Daily, Weekly and Monthly. Can we set it up for hourly/ by minute ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not in a position to test this, but it appears that hourly (but not "minutely") **may** be possible, but only via an **unsupported** route.

Subscription details are held in the APEX table called `WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET_NOTIFY`, with the frequency in column `NOTIFY_INTERVAL` which is defined as `VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)`.  There is a constraint `WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET_NOTIFY_CK` on this column defined as:

```
notify_interval in ('H','D','BW','W','M')
```

So it appears that at some point in the past hourly ('H') and bi-weekly ('BW') were permitted values.  Of course, 'BW' is impossible as the column holds only one character.

So you could try updating this value in the table to 'H' and see what happens!